# Experience building and using Qt Embedded

Tags: linux, qt, embedded, makefile, compilation

I am currently trying to compile and build QT for Embedded Linux on an Ubuntu box for ARM architecture.  So far, I have run into MANY errors while trying to MAKE.  The biggest one being a 2000 line C++ function which caused a compiler error.  What are other peoples experiences with this and how did you fix it?

Comment: It will be helpful if you can post the error messages.

Comment: Yes, the error message is very important.  If it's an ICE (internal compiler error), it's almost certainly a compiler bug; for example, (if I recall correctly) GCC 4.3.3 can't compile Qt 4.5.0's QString on certain architectures due to this.  If it's a linking error, your setup or configuration is probably incorrect.

Comment: I managed to get the 4.4.0 source to compile for ARM architecture.  So here is where I stand...

I compiled the Qt for X11 on my Ubuntu machine and its working fine, I can write and compile code into hello world, etc on my ubuntu box.

I compiled QT for embedded 4.4.0 in ARM architecture (./configure -embedded arm) and then "make" and now I have the resulting files from make.  I tried to open them through my network on the arm board running linux.  Is this the correct way to run QT on embedded...can I just run it like that? Qt Install docs are confusing to me and I have used linux 2+ years.

Comment: I get the following when I try to run the qmake command when in the /qt-embedded-opensource-src-4.4.0-rc1/bin folder with the ARM board


./qmake: line 1: syntax error: "&" unexpected (expecting ")")

Comment: That is not a compiler error at all, there's something wrong with your buildsystem.  Can you edit your question to remove "compiler error" and to include your setup, the command you are running and its failure?  (<pre></pre> will be useful.)

Comment: It takes a right kind of environment to get it running. If you have that, then compilation itself is a breeze. so the question is, what sort of environment are you building your qt: cross-compiler, on actual arm platform or scratchbox/qemu alike ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My experience has always been favorable, given:

You must follow every single instruction in the installation instructions for Qt, without exception.  Every time I've run into compilation errors, it's been because I tried to just do it quickly, instead of reading the attached documentation for that specific platform.

I'd review the instructions - there's probably some minor thing that needs to be done first, which will most likely eliminate your errors.