# Is Qt for Embedded Linux supported for a Target embedded machine running Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt5, qtgui

I want to create a full screen Qt application running directly to the frame buffer, without the X Window System in Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit embedded device (Intel Atom Quad-core processor). So I thought `Qt for Embedded Linux` would be the best way to go. But according to Qt website the options are either Embedded Android or Embedded Linux Software Stack. I need Ubuntu and not other Linux distros like Angstrom because the dependencies for the Qt app was tested for Ubuntu 12.04.

I have found similar questions being asked, but still am not sure whether it is possible.

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/3009

[Experience building and using Qt Embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002667/experience-building-and-using-qt-embedded)

Can someone please point me in the right direction or whether its possible? Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Qt for Embedded Linux supported for a Target embedded machine running Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit?

It feels strange that you wish to use Ubuntu and you want to avoid using X. This is a sort of paradoxon.

Either way, Qt 5 has different backends, like eglfs, linuxfb, directb, and so forth as plugins. You can use them on desktop, too. This is not strictly restricted to "embedded".

Just make sure you pick up the appropriate plugin when running your application. [Here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/51f7ef800ee84f9cbc0e1f742c2d869f887bd5ed%3asrc/plugins/platforms) you can see the detailed list of the available plugins.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps I have been thinking wrong about avoiding X. I just want to have a single front-end GUI app running on the machine while the back-end has CLI programs. Also, the app will call some already compiled binaries in the background - so I don't want to focus on recompiling it for any other OS.

Comment: @user3391000: so what is the issue?

Comment: Sorry I have a huge knowledge gap - just started looking at Qt in hope to create a full screen standalone GUI app at system boot. Will Qt for Embedded Linux still work on top of the existing Ubuntu installation? Perhaps I can just remove the existing GNOME desktop environment, use Qt/X11. Just want to prevent use manipulating the window - like a complete embedded product. Any more ideas based on this clarification?

Comment: @user3391000: yes, you just write your application, and start from the init system.